# ¿Referencia de objeto no establecida ServiceLocator.Current para inyección de dependencias en ASPX?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estoy intentando revisar un código ASPX pero la siguiente linea me manda un error de Referencia de objeto no establecida (ServiceLocator.Current), pido que si hay alguien que me pueda poner en contexto sobre que me hace falta para que no tenga el error

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();


namespace Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
{
    public static class ServiceLocator
    {
        public static IServiceLocator Current { get; }

        public static void SetLocatorProvider(ServiceLocatorProvider newProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar como tiene la definición de ServiceLocator?

Comment: @M.Gress he agregado la definición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho una mala referencia al ensamblado, el namespace correcto es "CommonServiceLocator", en lugar de "Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation"

Solucionado